# Instanciar fecha con formato GMT+2 en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Soy incapaz de obtener una instancia de una fecha con el formato GMT+2, es decir, a partir de la cadena de texto `2022-10-01 00:00:00 GMT+2` quiero obtener un objeto `datetime`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```py
time_gmt: str = '2022-10-01 00:00:00 GMT+2'
mi_fecha = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_gmt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

El error que obtengo con dicho formato es: `ValueError: unconverted data remains: +2`, porque no sabe que hacer con ese "+2" del GMT. He buscado en https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html el formato para ver si es incorrecto pero no me queda muy claro si hay que añadirle algo más, o tratarlo de otra forma.

En la documentación indica el siguiente fragmento:

> In strftime(), `%Z` is replaced by an empty string if tzname() returns `None`; otherwise `%Z` is replaced by the returned value, which must be a string.
>
> strptime() only accepts certain values for `%Z`:
>
> 1. any value in `time.tzname` for your machine’s locale
> 2. the hard-coded values `UTC` and `GMT`
>
> So someone living in Japan may have `JST`, `UTC`, and `GMT` as valid values, but probably not `EST`. It will raise `ValueError` for invalid values.

Por el error que me aparece, entiendo que `GMT+2` no es un valor válido, pero entonces, ¿cual sería un valor válido?

Mi único objetivo es a partir de una cadena similar a esta `2022-10-01 00:00:00 GMT+2` obtener un objeto `datetime`. Si alguien sabe alguna forma de conseguirlo, su ayuda será bienvenida.

Un saludo

PD: gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras pero hay una pequeña confusión, `%Z` (Con mayúscula) sirve para identificar el nombre de la zona horaria y `%z` (Con minúscula) para asignar la compensación o desplazamiento en formato `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]`

Por lo que quedaría así:

```
import datetime

time_gmt: str = '2022-10-01 00:00:00 GMT+0200'
mi_fecha = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_gmt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z')
```

Y ahora vemos que `mi_fecha` es un objeto de tipo `datetime` que tiene un desplazamiento o `timedelta` de `7200` segundos que son 2 horas y la zona horaria es `GMT`

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'GMT'))
```

Si imprimes únicamente `mi_fecha` vas a obtener lo siguiente:

```
2022-10-01 00:00:00+02:00
```

Si deseas ver `mi_fecha` con el formato que deseas entonces tienes que incluir el formato al imprimir:

```
 print(mi_fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
```

Ejemplo desde la terminal:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time_gmt = '2022-10-01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00'
>>> mi_fecha = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_gmt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z')
>>> mi_fecha
datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'GMT'))
>>> print(mi_fecha)
2022-10-01 00:00:00+02:00
>>> print(mi_fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
2022-10-01 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, estuve probando `%Z%z`, pero ya veo que al `GMT+` le tienen que seguir `02:00` ó `0200` y no sólo `2`, que ahí estaba mi problema, mi valor no válido. De nuevo, muchas gracias